# Is it possible to call a Javascript function (that's private) inside the object A from an object that inherits from A?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to test some inner functions that I have without putting the Javascript test code in the same file. I've been trying to inherit the class that has the inner functions, and then adding wrapper functions to make them public, like this:

```
copyPrototype(TrafficChartCanvas_test, TrafficChartCanvas);

function TrafficChartCanvas_test() {

    TrafficChartCanvas_test.prototype.test_getYScale = function(reach) {
        return getYScale(reach);
    }
}
```

Assume copyPrototype successfully assigns the prototype of TrafficChartCanvas to that of TrafficChartCanvas_test. Here's part of the file I'm attempting to test:

```
function TrafficChartCanvas(...) {

    // some other stuff here... public functions, etc.

    function getYScale(reach) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work for me. Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getYScale` isn't part of `TrafficChartCanvas`'s prototype, it's within its *closure*.  They're two very different things.

You could change the way you create `TrafficChartCanvas` and restructure your code something like:

```
TrafficChartCanvas.prototype = {
  // (... Other functions ...)
  getYScale: function() {
      ...
  }
}
```

This puts the function in the prototype and allows it to be tested using tests written and included in another file.  You can't keep functions private within a closure *and* make the accesible for external testing; you'll have to go the prototype route.

Comment: I see, I guess I am asking how can I make TrafficChartCanvas's closure also available to TrafficChartCanvas_test?

Comment: Not exactly, you'd want to define the class a different way... I'll update my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Yes see I understand that would work, but I wanted to keep the function private. I guess I'll have to just deal with this solution

Answer (score 1):

The "TrafficChartCanvas" function can arrange for a way to explicitly export the function, but short of that, no there's no way to do it.

Comment: So there is no way I can test this function outside of TrafficChartCanvas's scope without making it part of the prototype?

Comment: Check @searlea's answer.  The function has to be explicitly "exported", either by directly attaching it to the prototype, or by providing another function to retrieve it.